# What's the meaning behind open and closed parentheses?

Tags: javascript, parentheses

What is the point or meaning behind having code that has open and closes parentheses?

Here's the sample code that I'm looking at:

```
<input style="background-color:#bfdfff" name="fn" type="text" id="kfn" 
    size="55" maxlength="55" onfocus=                   
        "this.select(); 
        if (this.value==''){
          this.style.background='#00CCCC';
        }
        else
        {
          this.style.background='#99CCFF';
        }
" />
```

The line I'm curious about is here:

```
this.select();
```

What's the meaning of using open and close brackets `()`?

Comment: Friendly tip: you might get banned from asking questions here at SO if you keep deleting your own questions or getting them closed. Please think twice before posting questions and make sure it doesn't exist yet and with proper syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THose are called *parentheses*, not "brackets". They enclose the arguments to a function call. The function `select` doesn't take any arguments, but you still have to put the parentheses there to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what ernest said, it also helps to identify a function rather than just a variable.
Without the parentheses you would have no idea if something was a function or a variable if you were unfamiliar with the code.

Comment: Without the parentheses it would still be a function. You could do something like `b.x = a.x;`.

Comment: It would depend on the language and the compiler. Visual Basic does not use parentheses for non-parenthesesised functions.

Comment: But we're not talking about Visual Basic. We're talking about JavaScript.

Comment: Also, you can have functions in JavaScript without needed parenthesis. Every heard of [getters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)?